# What is poetry, What is time, What is rhythm, What is rhyme?

Tags: riddle, poetry

### The sun that hides underneath his belt, a new horizon, that none shall melt.

What is a bird that never flies, or a heart that never dies?
Can a man be saved by grace alone, or runs a river that cries.
To wake to sleep, each morn, each day. Build up the walls that tear away.
Find the meaning, of a story untold that two sustain on volcanoes.